# slurm: How to connect front-end with compute nodes?

Tags: slurm

I have a front end and two compute nodes

All have same slurm.conf file which ends with (for detail please see: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/46b56cd3a29120594773ae1c8bc4b72c):

```
NodeName=ebloc2 NodeHostName=ebloc NodeAddr=54.227.62.43 CPUs=1
PartitionName=debug Nodes=ebloc2 Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP

NodeName=ebloc4 NodeHostName=ebloc NodeAddr=54.236.173.82 CPUs=1
PartitionName=debug Nodes=ebloc4 Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

`slurmctld`: only checks first written nodes information and does not check the second written node's. When I try to send a job I recieve following error, it handles only first written node's IP and when I run `sudo slurmd` on the first node it works.

**Error:**

```
slurmctld: debug2: slurm_connect failed: Connection refused
slurmctld: debug2: Error connecting slurm stream socket at 54.227.62.43:6821: Connection refused
slurmctld: debug2: slurm_connect failed: Connection refused
slurmctld: debug2: Error connecting slurm stream socket at 54.227.62.43:6821: Connection refused
```

The problem: compute node that I mentioned in the first order receives the jobs but the compute node I mentioned on the second order does not. How could I fix it.

slurmctld logs(https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/4ec8c1b15e0ada4aa4bd0414e2b1ffb4)

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your config right now, but maybe try to: 1) remove NodeHostName (the same name is repeated, I believe it shouldn't be); 2) remove the first PartitionName line (it's repeated, and you have only 1 partition); 3) edit the second PartitionName line to 'Nodes=ebloc2,ebloc4'. Also, make sure the headnode and both nodes have the same slurm.conf (your logs show errors about that)

Comment: When I remove `NodeHostName` slurmctld gives an error: `slurmctld: fatal: Frontend not configured correctly in slurm.conf.  See man slurm.conf look for frontendname.` I think I should keep it. @angmo

Comment: I second every comment of @angmo, and you should furthermore make sure that ebloc2 and ebloc4 and ebloc are indeed the result of the `hostname -s` command on the compute nodes and controller node respectively

Comment: All nodes hostname was returning `ebloc` I guess that was the main reason of the error. As I understand ebloc2 's `hostname -s` should return `ebloc2`,  `ebloc4 ` 's `hostname -s` should return `ebloc4` and so on, right? @damienfrancois

Comment: When I change compute node's hostname from ebloc to ebloc2 slurmd gives following error: "slurmd: fatal: Unable to determine this slurmd's NodeName" @damienfrancois

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the configuration file, try removing `ControlAddr=127.0.0.1`; or replacing with the IP address of `ebloc`. This `127.0.0.1` address  basically means 'myself' and  `ControlAddr` is used by `slurmd` to connect to the controller.

Remove also `NodeHostName=localhost NodeAddr=127.0.0.1` for the same reason.

And make sure that `ebloc` and `ebloc1` and `ebloc2` are indeed what `hostname -s` returns on those machines.

Also make sure no firewall blocs the Slurm ports in any direction between those machines, and that SELinux is disabled or permissive. Make sure `slurmd` runs, as well as `munge`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one `PartitionName` line per partition.
Remove the first one and put:

```
PartitionName = debug Nodes=ebloc2,ebloc4 Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

or use regexp:

```
PartitionName = debug Nodes=ebloc[2,4] Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```