# How could I run Open MPI under Slurm

Tags: openmpi, slurm, sbatch

I am unable to run `Open MPI` under `Slurm` through a `Slurm-script`.

In general, I am able to obtain the hostname and run `Open MPI` on my machine.

```
$ mpirun hostname
myHost
$ cd NPB3.3-SER/ && make ua CLASS=B && mpirun -n 1 bin/ua.B.x inputua.data # Works
```

---

But if I do the same operation through the slurm-script `mpirun hostname` returns empty string and consequently I am unable to run `mpirun -n 1 bin/ua.B.x inputua.data`.

*slurm-script.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -o slurm.out        # STDOUT
#SBATCH -e slurm.err        # STDERR
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/openmpi/lib"
mpirun hostname > output.txt # Returns empty
cd NPB3.3-SER/ 
make ua CLASS=B 
mpirun --host myHost -n 1 bin/ua.B.x inputua.data
```

```
$ sbatch -N1 slurm-script.sh
Submitted batch job 1
```

---

The error I am receiving:

```
There are no allocated resources for the application
  bin/ua.B.x
that match the requested mapping:    
------------------------------------------------------------------
Verify that you have mapped the allocated resources properly using the
--host or --hostfile specification.

A daemon (pid unknown) died unexpectedly with status 1 while attempting
to launch so we are aborting.

There may be more information reported by the environment (see above).

This may be because the daemon was unable to find all the needed shared
libraries on the remote node. You may set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to have the
location of the shared libraries on the remote nodes and this will
automatically be forwarded to the remote nodes.
------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that the job aborted, but has no info as to the process
that caused that situation.
------------------------------------------------------------------
An ORTE daemon has unexpectedly failed after launch and before
communicating back to mpirun. This could be caused by a number
of factors, including an inability to create a connection back
to mpirun due to a lack of common network interfaces and/or no
route found between them. Please check network connectivity
(including firewalls and network routing requirements).
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: just remove the `--host myHost` option altogether. If SLURM was compiled with OpenMPI integration, it would be able to pass the list of allocated nodes to mpirun implicitly.

Comment: I have removed `--host myHost` but still I am having the same error. I have compiled SLURM as follows `./configure --enable-debug --enable-front-end && make && make install`. How could I compile SLURM with OpenMPI integration? @DmitriChubarov

Comment: Could you give slurm and openmpi versions?

Comment: What do you get if you run `hostname` (not `mpirun hostname`) via `slurm`? This could discriminate whether `openmpi` is involved in the issue.
My guess is most likely openmpi has nothing to do with `output.txt` being empty (I wouldn't know if that is the *only* problem you have, or simply the first to show up).

Comment: If I run `hostname` via `slurm` it returns `ebloc` that is actually the `NodeHostName` on `slurm.conf` as well. @sancho.s

Comment: Please compare the results of executing exactly the same `mpirun` command via command line and slurm.
You are not using `--host` in the command line.

Comment: Via command line `mpirun -n 1 bin/ua.B.x inputua.data` works without an error. But interestingly using `--host` on command line:`mpirun --host myHost -n 1 bin/ua.B.x inputua.data` generated following error: `This may be because the daemon was unable to find all the needed shared
libraries on the remote node. You may set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to have the
location of the shared libraries on the remote nodes and this will
automatically be forwarded to the remote nodes.`

Comment: Conversely, what happens if you execute `mpirun` without `--host` via slurm?
That seems to be (part of?) the problem.
Perhaps `/usr/lib/openmpi/lib` is not the correct path. In my system, for example, it is `/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib`

Comment: In addition, what OS do you have?
Why do you compile slurm instead of using an available package?

Comment: While waiting for your confirmation on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `mpirun` without `--host` in a slurm script, please see updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

If Slurm and OpenMPI are recent versions, make sure that OpenMPI is compiled with Slurm support (run `ompi_info | grep slurm`  to find out) and just run `srun bin/ua.B.x inputua.data` in your submission script.

Alternatively, `mpirun bin/ua.B.x inputua.data` should work too.

If OpenMPI is compiled without Slurm support the following should work:

```
srun hostname > output.txt
cd NPB3.3-SER/ 
make ua CLASS=B 
mpirun --hostfile output.txt -n 1 bin/ua.B.x inputua.data
```

Make sure also that by running `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/openmpi/lib"` you do not overwrite other library paths that are necessary. Better would probably be `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/lib/openmpi/lib"` (or [a more complex version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162891/append-to-path-like-variable-without-creating-leading-colon-if-unset) if you want to avoid a leading `:` if it were initially empty.)

Comment: I am still having the same errors that I have represented on my question for `mpirun bin/ua.B.x inputua.data` .I have updated  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, Unfortunately `srun` doesn't work. I can run `bin/sp.B.x inputsp.data` without any problem. 
// `$ srun hostname > output.txt` =>
`srun: error: srun task launch not supported on this system`

// `$ ompi_info | grep slurm` =>
`MCA ras: slurm (MCA v2.0, API v2.0, Component v1.6.5)
MCA plm: slurm (MCA v2.0, API v2.0, Component v1.6.5)
MCA ess: slurm (MCA v2.0, API v2.0, Component v1.6.5)
MCA ess: slurmd (MCA v2.0, API v2.0, Component v1.6.5)`

Comment: If you have `FrontEnd` defined in your `slurm.conf`, remove it.

Comment: I guest `FrontEnd` is not defined, //`cat /usr/local/etc/slurm.conf | grep "FrontEnd"` returns empty line. @damienfrancois

Comment: Then check that the names in the `slurm.conf` file match those of the servers (`hostname -s`). Also make sure `slurm.conf` is identical on all machines?

Comment: Currently I am using Slurm on a single machine and able to submit jobs via `sbatch` but not with `srun`. `hostname -s` matches with `ControlMachine` and `NodeHostName` in the `slurm.conf`. Please note that I wasn't not able to manage to make Slurm work on multiple machines due to the problem I have faced that asked before (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719897/slurm-how-to-connect-front-end-with-compute-nodes).

Comment: Is `slurmd` running as `root`?

Comment: Yes `slurmd` is running as root; please see how I start running `slurm`: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/29ff065c98c63a99cf2d647ec5dc1d3d @damienfrancois

Comment: did you compile slurm by yourself?

Comment: Yes I have compiled `slurm` from its source code => The way I compile and build is as follows: `$ git clone  https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm
$ cd slurm
$ ./configure --enable-debug --enable-front-end
$ sudo make install`

Comment: Try removing that part: `--enable-front-end`. It is meant for specific architectures and sometimes abused to simulate a larger cluster on a single server. This is not what you want. You want a regular Slurm install with only one server that runs both controller and `slurmd`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is: 1) run `mpirun`, 2) from `slurm`, 3) with `--host`.
To determine who is responsible for this not to work (**Problem 1**), you could test a few things.
Whatever you test, you should test *exactly* the same via command line (*CLI*) and via `slurm` (*S*).
It is understood that some of these tests will produce different results in cases *CLI* and *S*.

A few notes are:
1) You are not testing *exactly* the same things in CLI and S.
2) You say that you are "unable to run `mpirun -n 1 bin/ua.B.x inputua.data`", while the problem is actually with `mpirun --host myHost -n 1 bin/ua.B.x inputua.data`.
3) The fact that `mpirun hostname > output.txt` returns an empty file (**Problem 2**) does not necessarily have the same origin as your main problem, see paragraph above. You can overcome this problem by using `scontrol show hostnames`
or with the environment variable `SLURM_NODELIST` (on which `scontrol show hostnames` is based), but this will not solve Problem 1.

---

To work around **Problem 2**, which is not the most important, try a few things via both CLI and S.
The slurm script below may be helpful.

```
#SBATCH -o slurm_hostname.out        # STDOUT
#SBATCH -e slurm_hostname.err        # STDERR
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:}/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib"

mpirun hostname > hostname_mpirun.txt               # 1. Returns values ok for me
hostname > hostname.txt                             # 2. Returns values ok for me
hostname -s > hostname_slurmcontrol.txt             # 3. Returns values ok for me
scontrol show hostnames > hostname_scontrol.txt     # 4. Returns values ok for me
echo ${SLURM_NODELIST} > hostname_slurmcontrol.txt  # 5. Returns values ok for me
```

(for an explanation of the `export` command see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/415028/137608)).
From what you say, I understand 2, 3, 4 and 5 work ok for you, and 1 does not.
So you could now use `mpirun` with suitable options `--host` or `--hostfile`.

Note the different format of the output of `scontrol show hostnames` (e.g., for me `cnode17<newline>cnode18`) and `echo ${SLURM_NODELIST}` (`cnode[17-18]`).

The host names could perhaps also be obtained in file names set dynamically with `%h` and `%n` in [`slurm.conf`](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html), look for e.g. `SlurmdLogFile`, `SlurmdPidFile`.

---

To diagnose/work around/solve **Problem 1**, try `mpirun` with/without `--host`, in CLI and S.
From what you say, assuming you used the correct syntax in each case, this is the outcome:

1. `mpirun`, CLI (original post).
   "Works".
2. `mpirun`, S (comment?).
   Same error as item 4 below?
   Note that `mpirun hostname` in S should have produced similar output in your `slurm.err`.
3. `mpirun --host`, CLI (comment).
   Error

   ```
   There are no allocated resources for the application bin/ua.B.x that match the requested mapping:
   ...
   This may be because the daemon was unable to find all the needed shared
   libraries on the remote node. You may set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to have the
   location of the shared libraries on the remote nodes and this will
   automatically be forwarded to the remote nodes.
   ```
4. `mpirun --host`, S (original post).
   Error (same as item 3 above?)

   ```
   There are no allocated resources for the application
     bin/ua.B.x
   that match the requested mapping:    
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
   Verify that you have mapped the allocated resources properly using the
   --host or --hostfile specification.
   ...
   This may be because the daemon was unable to find all the needed shared
   libraries on the remote node. You may set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to have the
   location of the shared libraries on the remote nodes and this will
   automatically be forwarded to the remote nodes.
   ```

As per comments, you may have a wrong `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` path set.
You may also need to use `mpi --prefix ...`

Related?
https://github.com/easybuilders/easybuild-easyconfigs/issues/204

Comment: `$ scontrol show hostnames` => `scontrol: error: host list is empty`
`$ echo ${SLURM_NODELIST} # Returns empty`

In addition to that I have run `slurm_test.slurm`. `hostname_mpirun.txt` is not created.

`$ cat hostname_slurmcontrol.txt` => `ebloc`
`$ cat hostname.txt` => `ebloc`

Comment: @alper - I mean to get the output of `scontrol` in slurm, not the command line.
Please post the contents of `slurm_hostname.out`. I expect to find there the host name. In addition, it seems `hostname` outputs the host name correctly.

Comment: `$ cat slurm.out` => 
`ebloc1
ebloc1`

Comment: @alper - Is that not enough for using it as the host name where to `mpirun`?
What is your expected output?

Comment: I have updated `myHost` as `ebloc1` but still I am having the same error. Please see the error in depth: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/b61f29a60643dc104c4c1a4945374208. I think as @damienfrancois suggested I need to re-compile `slurm` without `--enable-front-end` flag and try again.

Comment: @alper - So the problem seems to be with `mpirun`, regardless of slurm.
Please post the results of `mpirun -n 1 --host ... bin/ua.B.x inputua.data` (that piece of information was missing).
What do you mean by "the same error". What are you exactly executing?

Comment: Please see the result of `mpirun -n 1 --host ... bin/ua.B.x inputua.data` from this link: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/b61f29a60643dc104c4c1a4945374208 // `There are no allocated resources for the application
  bin/ua.B.x
that match the requested mapping:`